# Getting random documents from MongoDB In Yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

How can I get N random documents from MongoDB (using Yii2)?

Is there some special method, like

```
Products::find()->random(20)->asArray()->all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have created an database connection component as mongodb

```
$collection = \Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('yourcollection');
$result = $collection->aggregate([
            [
                "\$sample" => ["size"=>20]
            ]
          ]);
vardump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as MongoDB is concerned you can use the aggregation framework [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) (new in version 3.2) for that purpose:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    { $sample: { size: 20 } }
])
```

The above aggregation will select 20 random documents from the products collection.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but how would I do that in Yii2?

Comment: @alexandernst I thought your problem was the mongo query. I've never used Yii2, [but looking at the docs it has an aggregate function that uses the aggregation framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-collection.html#aggregate()-detail).